# Select the closest class to a clicked element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to show/hide the closest text-box class for each individual button press? not all at once?

```js
$(".text-box").hide();

$(".read-more").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".text-box").show();
});
$(".read-less").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".text-box").hide();
});
```

```css
.text-box {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-box">text box text</div>
<div class="body-text">body text</div>
<button class="button">reveal text</button>
<button class="button read-less">hide text</button>

<div class="text-box">test box text</div>
<div class="body-text">body text</div>
<button class="button">reveal text</button>
<button class="button read-less">hide text</button>

<div class="text-box">test box text</div>
<div class="body-text">body text</div>
<button class="button read-more">reveal text</button>
<button class="button read-less">hide text</button>
```

Comment: pls paste your html code also, we can't check all the things

Comment: I pasted the website that it currently lives on...

Comment: @whoami, I edited my post...do you know the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest()` won't do the job for you because it runs through the parents returning the closest parent, but you can do this, if you don't want to change your HTML wrapping your sections in extra div blocks.

```js
$(function() {
$(".text-box").hide();

$(".read-more").on("click", function() {
   $(this).prevAll('.text-box').first().show();
});
$(".read-less").on("click", function() {
   $(this).prevAll('.text-box').first().hide();
});
});
```

```css
.text-box {
 /* float: right; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-box">text box text 1</div>
<div class="body-text">body text</div>
<button class="button read-more">reveal text</button>
<button class="button read-less">hide text</button>

<div class="text-box">test box text 2</div>
<div class="body-text">body text</div>
<button class="button read-more">reveal text</button>
<button class="button read-less">hide text</button>

<div class="text-box">test box text 3</div>
<div class="body-text">body text</div>
<button class="button read-more">reveal text</button>
<button class="button read-less">hide text</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `prevAll()` in conjunction with `first()`:

```
$(".read-more").on("click", function() {
  $(this).prevAll(".text-box").first().show();
});
$(".read-less").on("click", function() {
  $(this).prevAll(".text-box").first().hide();
});
```

`prevAll(".text-box")` gets all previous siblings that matches the selector `.text-box`, and `first()` returns the first of them.

Comment: I'm sorry you wrote the same thing as me as I was trying to make a complete example snippet. I didn't even know you post the same style answer! I'll give UP to your answer, for compensation, first because is correct way and second because it seems you post it before me.

Comment: This is a good answer, but doesn't work for me on the site I'm trying to do it with. It's a Drupal site...mostcenter.org/featured-stories   There is a hidden element with the class of "featured-left-information" on that site that I'm trying to hide/show. I just got back into work, had the weekend off and I am stuck still. :( Thanks for your answer. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @Nick0989 jQuery traversing methods rely on your HTML structure. If you use the structure you wrote in your question, this is the way. Also you can change your structure to what other users have proposed. But of course neither my answer nor their answers work for every HTML tree that you can build. You can post a question with the real HTML and probably you'll get the solution quickly.

Comment: I did some research at work this morning and I actually figured it out. I had always thought that "closest" was moving down the DOM searching for any child elements, but it's not, it's moving up it to the ancestor...I had "Find" and "closest" confused...I did a little html restructuring in Drupal so it works I think.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to use `closest()` to find a sibling to the element.  However, closest goes up through the dom of the element's parents, not siblings.  I would suggest that you give each logical group a wrapping element, so they share a common parent, and then you can properly use closest in conjunction with find to get the element you want to target for a change.

```js
$(".text-box").hide();

$(".read-more").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('.text-container').find(".text-box").show();
});
$(".read-less").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('.text-container').find(".text-box").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text-container">
  <div class="text-box">text box text</div>
  <div class="body-text">body text</div>
  <button class="button read-more">reveal text</button>
  <button class="button read-less">hide text</button>
</span>

<span class="text-container">
  <div class="text-box">text box text</div>
  <div class="body-text">body text</div>
  <button class="button read-more">reveal text</button>
  <button class="button read-less">hide text</button>
</span>

<span class="text-container">
  <div class="text-box">text box text</div>
  <div class="body-text">body text</div>
  <button class="button read-more">reveal text</button>
  <button class="button read-less">hide text</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Yes I've tried this repeatedly actually. I've tried .parent() as well. I actually should get rid of the featured-left-information:first part too.

Comment: I edited my post, do you know the answer? I tried your way without any luck.

Comment: @Nick0989 updated answer based on the edited question.